# on dragover change background of div

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background of the div that the item is being dragged to.

I have also setup a counter that updates when something is being dragged over it (in my case its a file from my desktop). The counter portion is working properly but the background color does not change. What am i doing wrong?

```
var drop = document.getElementById('drop1');


// Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
    addEventHandler(drop, 'dragover', function (e) {
        e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE) 
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        fileNumber = fileNumber + 1;
        status.innerHTML = fileNumber;
        $("#drop1").css("background-color",'#AA0000');
        //$('drop1').css('background-color', '#AA0000');

        return true;
    });
```

and the html looks like this

```
<DIV id="drop1">Drop files here   
   <h1 align=center>A File Preview Demo</h1>
   <DIV id="status">Drag the files from a folder to a selected area ...</DIV>
   <DIV id="drop2">Drop files here.</DIV>
   <DIV id="list"></DIV>
   <DIV id="list2"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`$("#drop1").css({"background-color":"#AA0000"});`

Your fiddle didn't have jQuery enabled. [jQuery Enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/75/)

Comment: that had no effect. Here is the code that i am testing out in jfiddle. Give it a shot if you can. Just drag a file into the yellow area. http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/69/

Comment: In your fiddle you have `$("drop1").css("background-color", '#AA0000');` so you're missing the '#' sign on the identifier. What you posted here looks right. And remember to turn on jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: the line where the # was missing was commented. I have removed it. Now only the correct code is there still it does not work. This is what i have there now. $("#drop1").css({"background-color":"#AA0000"});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/74/ As Robb said, the code is right except the "#" was missing and jQuery wasn't present. Check the console for errors! Also just in case you keep working with drag event in pure html. `dragleave` and `dragenter` do not work like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Entering a child will trigger a `dragleave` even though you didn't really left the parent.

Comment: Yup. was missing the jQuery extention. Changed that in the dropdown and now its working. Thanks for the help